# spring difference between value and ref

Tags: java, spring

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/constructor_based_dependency_injection.htm

My question is in the last sentence of this tutorial.

```
 A final note, in case you are passing a reference to an object, 
 you need to use ref attribute of <constructor-arg> tag and 
 if you are passing a value directly then you should use value    
 attribute as shown above.
```

I am a little bit confused by what is reference of an object and what is an value.

Can I say that all the primary types is value, all the java class and beans is references?

What else might be used as reference here?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference this points to another spring bean.

a value is a true value being inputted. E.g. "foo" or "1"

Comment: A java class will be instantiated using a bean. So will need to give that bean an id then reference it using the "ref" field